# C++ - Qt - Visual Studio 2010 - application with both gui and console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

If no arguments are given to the program it launches as a GUI application, if it is given args it is run through the command line.  I was able to get visual studio to display and print to the console with Properties>Linker>SubSystem (Console/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE), but this makes it so that the console always displays when the application is launched, how can I selectively display the console so that when the app is run with the GUI it does not appear.  I have looked through the site, but all I have found is how to set it to only be a windows application, and I need it to function as both

Thanks!!!

Comment: How are you doing this in Qt?  Do you use both QApplication and QCoreApplication?  If not, have you tried QApplication *app; then if (argc == 1) app = new QCoreApplication(...); else app = new QApplication(...);?

Comment: right now what I'm doing is checking argc and if >1 I am not calling show() and using a separate constructor that sets up data and basically clicks for the user...  I'm not familiar with what you have above, I am new to C++ and to Qt...  Is the idea to have two full separate classes, one that is constructed in main if it's a gui and a different one if it is to be a console app?  cause this seems like I'd be doing a lot of duplication that I'm trying to avoid

Comment: QCoreApplication is a base class of QApplication inherits QCoreApplication.  QCoreApplication is for console apps.  (I should have declared QCoreApplication *app above).  I'm thinking if you assign app like I have above you should get a console app for argc == 1 and a gui app otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code I had lying around that creates a console and attaches input and output to it:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void Console::createConsole()
{
    AllocConsole();
    SetConsoleTitle("Debug console");

    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;

    FILE *fp;   // redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 ); 

    // redirect unbuffered STDIN to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "r" );
    *stdin = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );  

    // redirect unbuffered STDERR to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stderr = *fp;
    setvbuf( stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
}
```

I haven't used Qt but you should be able to stick that somewhere and make it work.

Edit: added the headers needed

Comment: This works somewhat but does not resolve the big issue. The OP wanted to use a console if parameters are passed. However if parameters are passed from a console, then a new console is opened and the existing one still does not receive any output.

Answer (score 4):

This works I guess:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>


int
main(int n_app_args, char **app_arg)
{
    QCoreApplication * application = 0;

    if ( n_app_args == 1 )
    {
        application = new QCoreApplication(n_app_args, app_arg);
    }
    else
    {
        application = new QApplication(n_app_args, app_arg);
        QMainWindow * mainWindow = new QMainWindow();
        mainWindow->show();
    }


    return application->exec();
}
```

Call it with an argument and you get a little (empty) window.  Call it with no argument and no window.

Comment: But does that solve the problem? If you compile with SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE you still get the console with QApplication and if you compile with SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS you get no output on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it using the windows subsystem, and calling [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you need a console while the application has a gui as well.

Comment: I'm finding references for using this for c# but not for c++, and am having trouble using it...  also all the references I am finding are not for Qt apps...

Comment: Not for Qt but have a look at this http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm & http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/win32gui/Win32Apps.htm