# Why doesn't stdin work when I create a console in a Visual Studio GUI app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, console, stdin

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215565/810671) to create a console in my Visual Studio 2010 GUI app, and connect up the standard I/O with the console. However, `stdin` still does not work (although `stdout` and `stderr` work perfectly fine). What am I doing wrong?

Here is my version of the code (slightly modified from the answer I linked to above):

```
static void create_console()
{
    AllocConsole();
    SetConsoleTitle(L"Python console");

    intptr_t stdin_handle = (intptr_t)GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    int conin_handle = _open_osfhandle(stdin_handle, _O_TEXT);
    FILE *fpin = _fdopen(conin_handle, "r");
    *stdout = *fpin;
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);

    intptr_t stdout_handle = (intptr_t)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int conout_handle = _open_osfhandle(stdout_handle, _O_TEXT);
    FILE *fpout = _fdopen(conout_handle, "w");
    *stdout = *fpout;
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);

    intptr_t stderr_handle = (intptr_t)GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    int conerr_handle = _open_osfhandle(stderr_handle, _O_TEXT);
    FILE *fperr = _fdopen(conerr_handle, "w");
    *stderr = *fperr;
    setvbuf(stderr, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);
}
```

One interesting thing I found was that while `fileno(stdout)` and `fileno(stderr)` returned normal values, namely `4` and `5`, `fileno(stdin)` returned `-2`, which is not even a documented error code of `fileno` (From the doc: "Otherwise, the value -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.").

Comment: `*stdout = *fpin` ???

Comment: @DieterLücking that would be it, thanks!